# Center QGroupBox in mainWindow

Tags: qt

I need to align groupbox in the center to mainWindow, here as the groupbox contains some textfield and button.

I have tried

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
 ui->groupBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);  
 ui->groupBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
}
```

But which doesn't make any changes on UI when I run the application.

Is this the right method or is there any better method?

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: The group box is the only widget on the mainwondow?

Comment: And is the groupbox inside a layout?

Comment: Can you show us image from your UI?

Comment: Hi I have uploaded the screen shot, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

In `virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * e)` do the following:

```
ui->groupBox->setWidth(200); // or derive the size as you like
ui->groupBox->setHeight(100);

ui->groupBox->moveTo(center() - QPoint(ui->groupBox->width()/2, ui->groupBox->height()/2));
```

This should keep your frame always in the center.
Note, that this approach doesn't need any layout.